# I've already deleted my timeline app but my profile is still showing the timeline

Tags: facebook-timeline

I've already deleted my timeline app but my profile is still showing the timeline... I'm trying to change it to my old profile, but since I've already deleted it and there is no apps, so I cannot edit it. Help! Thank you!